# event when a google maps InfoWindow is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there way to set an event on an InfoWindow that will notify me when that window is closed?  I've managed to find a hack that works: after setting the content of the InfoWindow by dom node, get the parentNode.previousSibling to that element (which will be the close button), and assign it an onclick.  However this is relying on behavior that could change, so obviously that's not so good.  Is there a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [closeclick event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow) if i get this right

Comment: Indeed you are right.  Sometimes the docs are a bit weirdly organized, but there it is.  :)

Comment: Link no longer exists